# Mismatch data between source table and target table

Tags: teradata

I loaded the table but source count and target count is mismatching.
Source Data is in Oracle and Target data is in Teradata. How i can find missing data in Target

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what approach/utility/tool you are using for migrating from Oracle to Teradata .Verify whether bad records are captured in any way.

If you are unable to find from above then do a count of record on a yearly/monthly basis on both databases.Export them in excel and do a comparison.From here you will find the range where missing records are there.From there you further root cause

st_date  end_date  count(1)

1-1-1999 31-12-1999 10000

1-1-2000 31-12-2000 10000

select min(u_date) as st_date, min(u_date)+365 ,count(1) from table

do a looping of the above query,till you reach max(date)

Answer (score 0):

The target table in Teradata is probably be a SET table disallowing duplicate rows.

If there's a Unique/Primary Key constraint in Oracle rows might still be considered duplicate by Teradata

- if a [Var]Char column is defined as NOT CASESPECIFIC, then 'a' and 'A' are equal
- if there are trailing spaces, 'a' and 'a '

Change the character columns to CASESPECIFIC and/or the table to MULTISET and try again.